# Кванторы всеобщности и частица «не»

Tags: грамотная-речь

Существуют ли в русском языке какие-либо правила, ограничивающие употребление слов «всякий, любой, каждый, все, всегда» в отрицательных предложениях? Вот примеры, записанные за медиа-персонами:

«Ни одного места, где можно было бы спрятать любое <…> сооружение» (диктор за кадром, канал 365, 20-16, 8.06.2012) /я бы сказала: «какое-либо сооружение»/

«Пенсионный возраст не минует каждого из нас» (Комсомольская правда в СПб, 22-29 сентября 2011, стр 7) /я бы сказала: никого из нас, ни одного из нас/

«Каждая из работ не остается незамеченной» (Комсомольская правда в СПб, 22-29 сентября 2011, стр 52 «Подмостки») /вместо: ни одна из работ/

«Мы всегда не должны забывать о самом главном» (5 канал, «Открытая студия», 17-56, 29.02.2012, гость программы) /вместо: никогда не должны /

«Не должны являться предметом обсуждения высшими официальными лицами любой страны.» (канал Россия, «Вести», диктор зачитывает заявление, 21-15, 15.08.2014)

«Всё истинно великое не теряется в веках» (канал ОТР, «Большая наука», диктор за кадром, 4-35, утро 27.08.2014)

«Любые попытки окрасить эту историю в цвета политики не имеют права на существование.» (канал Россия 24, репортер за кадром, 1=12, утро 18.09.2014)

«Любому нормальному человеку это не может нравиться.» (1 канал, «Время покажет», депутат, участник программы,  15-35, 10.10.2014)

«И любая помощь на этом пути не казалась лишней.» (РенТВ, «Территория заблуждений», ведущий И. Прокопенко, 4-10, утро 27.10.2014)

«Все скандалы, связанные с употреблением и хранением наркотиков, не погубили его карьеру.» (СТС, «Кино в деталях», женщина-репортер, 1-00, утро 28.10.2014)

Как вам такие тексты?

Answer (score 1):

Мне тоже не нравятся эти фразы. Их можно немного улучшить.

1. Если речь о том, что "дом - штука большая, его не спрячешь", то у диктора вышло, что "есть, конечно, места, где прячут сооружения, но отдельные сооружения и там не спрятать". Он спутал значения слов "любой" (какой угодно) и "какой-либо" (хоть какой-нибудь). Я бы исправил по Вашему рецепту.
2. Эта фраза не только стилистически неудачна, но и лукава (до пенсионного возраста у нас доживают далеко не все мужчины). Не очень хорошо представляю себе, как человека может "миновать" (пройти стороной, разминуться) или "не миновать" его пенсионный возраст, с ним можно разве что "поравняться", если дожить. Лучше оптимистично сказать: "каждого из нас ждёт..." или "у каждого впереди..."
3. Гибрид из "никогда не должны" и "всегда должны". "Должны не делать" возможно только во фразах с противопоставлением того, что именно вместо этого должны. Исправил бы по Вашему рецепту ("никогда не должны"). Ещё можно "должны помнить".
4. Здесь правильно "какой-либо" страны. Ещё неудачно совпадение падежей "(являться чем)" и "(обсуждения) кем".
5. Здесь лучше отбросить "всё", но можно и сказать "ничто".
6. Здесь нужно "Никакие".
7. Здесь я бы отбросил "Любому" (допустимо заменить на "никакому").
8. "Всякая помощь... казалась нелишней" либо "Никакая помощь... не казалась лишней".

Правил привести не могу, кроме известного Вам правила не считать речь журналистов эталоном :)

Comment: А это речь не только журналистов: (1) - перевод док. фильма, (5)- официальный документ. Я еще и за авторитетными людьми записываю: политиками, экспертами.  Речь журналистов должна быть эталонной, т.к. русский язык это главное, что скрепляет нашу страну, а СМИ - главное, что на него влияет.

Answer (score 0):

Примеры в деталях пока не смотрел, на вскидку - большинство, если не все, вполне корректны.
Но знаю, что (в принципе) никаких "ограничений" на "кванторы" в русском нет. Это не английский.

//--------
(+)

> > > «Ни одного места, где можно было бы спрятать любое <…> сооружение» (диктор за кадром, канал 365, 20-16, 8.06.2012) /я бы сказала: «какое-либо сооружение»/

Смысл разный. Какое-либо - это некоторое сооужение, конуру, например собачью.
Любое - это именно любое, вплоть до Асуанской плотины. Сомнительно, конечно, что автор имел в виду последнее, но наверняка этого знать нельзя.

> > «Пенсионный возраст не минует каждого из нас» (Комсомольская правда в СПб, 22-29 сентября 2011, стр 7) /я бы сказала: никого из нас, ни одного из нас/

Оба варианта правильны и синонимичны.

> > «Каждая из работ не остается незамеченной» (Комсомольская правда в СПб, 22-29 сентября 2011, стр 52 «Подмостки») /вместо: ни одна из работ/

Не вижу причин для замены. По смыслу - одно и тоже, нарушений грамматики нет.

> > «Мы всегда не должны забывать о самом главном» (5 канал, «Открытая студия», 17-56, 29.02.2012, гость программы) /вместо: никогда не должны /

Стилистическая шероховатость, не более.

> > «Не должны являться предметом обсуждения высшими официальными лицами любой страны.» (канал Россия, «Вести», диктор зачитывает заявление, 21-15, 15.08.2014)

Тоже, похоже, вы чересчур придираетесь.

> > «Всё истинно великое не теряется в веках» (канал ОТР, «Большая наука», диктор за кадром, 4-35, утро 27.08.2014)

Ну тут даже непонятно, к чему прицепиться.

> > «Любые попытки окрасить эту историю в цвета политики не имеют права на существование.» (канал Россия 24, репортер за кадром, 1=12, утро 18.09.2014)

Тоже не вижу причин считать ошибкой.

> > «Любому нормальному человеку это не может нравиться.» (1 канал, «Время покажет», депутат, участник программы, 15-35, 10.10.2014)

А мне нравится. )))

> > «И любая помощь на этом пути не казалась лишней.» (РенТВ, «Территория заблуждений», ведущий И. Прокопенко, 4-10, утро 27.10.2014)

И это нормально.

> > «Все скандалы, связанные с употреблением и хранением наркотиков, не погубили его карьеру.» (СТС, «Кино в деталях», женщина-репортер, 1-00, утро 28.10.2014)

Здесь-то что? Если измените на "никакие",  изменится и смысл. "Все" это именно все. В совокупности. А никакие - это значит, что "ни один". Неужели разницу не чувствуете? 
"Все полицейские не смогли связать преступника" vs "Никакие полицейские не смогли связать преступника".  
В вашем примере именно "все": *все* скандалы. Подразумевается что их было много и они, вероятно, были связаны друг с другом.

Надо ли править - не берусь сказать. Императивной необходимости не вижу. А кое-где, как в последнем примере, просто нельзя.

Comment: А в английском есть?

Comment: А английском да. Там - строго. В том можно усмотреть влияние почти абсолютного запрета на двойное отрицание. Например, ***ни***какой при ***не [бывает]*** невозможно, поэтому там требуется  - ***любой***. ***Аny*** и ***every*** никогда не смешиваются, хотя по смыслу, казалось бы, подходят оба. 
Правила четкие и строгие, настолько строгие, что русским с их вольностями интуитивно непонятны; их приходится объяснять, разбирая конкретные случаи. А уж англоязычные просто стонут от непонимания русского подхода. 
   
Вот ваши предлагаемые правки в чем-то будут близки англичанам. Но не во всем.

Comment: Да, @behemothus, вы правы.  Но согласитесь, что в русском какой-н. и любой имеют тонкое смысловое различие. В то время как в английском им соответствует один эквивалент - Аny (в вопросительном-отрицательном предложении) some (в утвердительном предложении). В этом плане в русском тяжелее. Автор полностью прав, указывая на ошибки журналистов.

Comment: Серж, какой-н. и любой имеют «толстое» смысловое различие и в русском, и в английском. Аny в вопросительном предложении - перевод: «какой-нибудь». Аny  в утвердительном предложении- перевод: «любой». Behemothus, «поэтому там требуется - любой». Просьба: составьте английское предложения с подлежащим «любой» и отрицанием в сказуемом. Что «Там - строго» насчет "кванторов", а не отрицаний? Где вы видели ограничения на их употребление? – дайте ссылку.

Comment: .@Тина не очень понял, ваш вопрос: "Просьба: составьте английское предложения с подлежащим «любой» и отрицанием в сказуемом. Что «Там - строго» насчет "кванторов", а не отрицаний? Где вы видели ограничения на их употребление? – дайте ссылку". Дать ссылку на что?

Comment: Вопрос не к вам а к @Behemothus, Вы пишете:"никакой при не [бывает] невозможно, поэтому там требуется – любой». Любой требуется вместо никакой? Если да, то составьте английское предложения с подлежащим «любой» и отрицанием в сказуемом. Что «Там - строго» = именно насчет "кванторов", а не отрицаний? Дайте ссылку на правила англ. грамматики, ограничивающие употребление кванторов всеобщности.

Comment: Тина, например, нельзя сказать: Там никого нет (два отрицания, заметье)/ Trere are not anybody there или Trere is nobody there. Заметье, предложение в английском построено с одним отрицанием.

Comment: @Серж "There" здесь подлежащее, а я просила, чтобы подлежащим было «любой», т.е. "any".  @Behemothus пишет: "никакой при не [бывает] невозможно, поэтому там требуется - любой." Русское подлежащее "никакой" при переводе на англ. он предлагает заменить на "любой", а это-то как раз и невозможно, поскольку при подлежащем   "any" сказуемое не может быть отрицательным.

Comment: Тина, ну все верно. Если в английском языке нужно построить предложение с словом "никакой"+отрицание, мы используем any вместо второго отрицания.Ср. предложения: Нет никакого сомнения. - There is not any doubt.There isn't any news in her letter.
В её письме нет никаких новостей.  (Нельзя сказать: There is not no doubt - Т.е. два отрицания.). @Behemothus писал именно об этом.Там о подлежащем речь не идет. Местоимение "any", в свою очередь, может употребляться в утвердительных предложениях в значении "любой", например: Take any cup you like. Бери любую кружку, какая тебе нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Тина, речь журналистов не всегда правильна. На грамоте есть раздел, где обсуждаются ошибки журналистов. И ошибки довольно-таки грубые. Можете зайти и прочитать. [Не говори шершавым языком](http://www.gramota.ru/biblio/research/rubric_370/)

Comment: Спасибо, почитала.

Comment: Итак, @Серж связь моих примеров с английским языком можно считать недоказанной. Вот еще пример на «всеобщность». Катя Гордон говорит: «Я перестала чувствовать к нему что угодно.» (11-05, 12.11.2014, РенТВ) Конечно, можно предположить, что именно это она и имела  в виду, т.е., что раньше она чувствовала к нему всё что угодно, ну просто что ни возьми- всё чувствовала, а вот теперь не так, но вероятнее всего, она хотела сказать что раньше чувствовала к нему нечто, а больше ничего не чувствует., Тогда ей лучше было бы выбрать вариант «Я перестала к нему что-либо чувствовать.»

Comment: Попробуйте перевести это на английский. Вдруг да обнаружится желанная связь?